# Error while installing tensorflow from pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, conda

i installed python and then installed anaconda. when i tried to install tensorflow from pip command i am getting this error. anyone know the reason?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.98]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>pip install tensorflow.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: try `pip install tensorflow==1.14.0` or use the latest version like `pip install tensorflow==2.0` and tell what you get. i.e specify the version you'd like to get installed.

Comment: Why install tensorflow through pip, if you're using Conda?

Answer (score 1):

The installation instructions for TensorFlow are located [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip). 
You'll see that there are a few more steps than just using pip. Long story short, once you're set up in a new environment use `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

That being said, you may want to use Anaconda to install it rather than pip. Anaconda is generally better as a package manager, and whenever you can you should be using Anaconda.